# Are ASP.Net sessions shared between iframes?

Tags: asp.net, session, iframe

Can two or more iframes share the same session data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Session data is stored by your server. Iframes are just "pages".

If the requests for both pages are served by the same server (or farm in the event of a suitably configured load-balanced environment), the requests have access to the same session data.

You can run into temporal issues in some circumstances; namely, if you set some session variable during the request for one page, but the other iframe expects that value to be set already, you won't have what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. If they are in the same web application they will share the same session